# How to deploy npm packages on fortrabbit, just like composer?

Tags: npm, fortrabbit

I wonder if there is a way to deploy npm packages on fortrabbit, just as smooth as fortrabbit handles composer packages?

I have tried

- call npm on the ssh cli (though fortrabbit docs says I can't make permanent change to file that way)
- fortrabbit.yml post event
- "koala-framework/composer-extra-assets" a composer extension, but it also calls npm, and fails

Now i wonder if there is a supported way to use npm. It seems fortrabbit docs have no mention of npm.

- hopefully, Søren

Answer (score 3):

fortrabbit is a PHP hosting service, but it doesn't let you use node.js or other languages.

So you can't use npm.

You can use a workflow where you commit your built files locally.